# Why differentiation of Fourier operator is difficult?

Tags: differentiation, fourier-transform, mathematics

I have a question when I read some papers about physics-informed neural networks.
In the paper of [physics-informed neural operator](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.03794), they said "it is non-trivial to compute the derivatives for Fourier neural operator" and proposed some efficient algorithms for this problem. But in the paper of [fourier neural operator](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.08895), I don't see they claim such a problem to compute these derivatives.

My thought is that pure fourier neural operator model still have to do backpropagation through the FFT and iFFT and therefore the derivatives of them is required, isn't it?